# Trying TDD with PHPUnit

Tags: testing

I'm trying out the built in test driven development method in Drupal 8 but I'm running in to a problem..

I'm getting the following errors when trying to run `./core/vendor/bin/phpunit --list-groups ./modules/` in my cli:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase' not found in
>       /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/modules/custom_cookie_compliance/
>       tests/CustomCookieComplianceTest.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase' not found in
>       /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/modules/custom_cookie_compliance/tests/
>       CustomCookieComplianceTest.php on line 10

I have created a module folder called custom_cookie_compliance in my modules folder. In turn I have a custom_cookie_compliance.info.yml file containing the following.

```
 name: Custom Cookie Compliance
 description: Displays a cookie compliance information window at the top of the website.
 core: 8.x
 type: module
```

I also have a *tests* folder containing a *src* folder which then contains a CustomCookieComplianceTest.php file with the following code.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\custom_cookie_compliance\Tests;

use Drupal\Tests\UnitTestCase;

/**
 * @group cookie
 */

class CustomCookieComplianceTest extends UnitTestCase {
  public function testSetCookies() {
    if (!isset($cookie_set)) {
      $cookie_set = TRUE;
    }

    $this->assertTrue($cookie_set);
  }
}
```

I have written the code by following [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2012184).

I understand it can't find the `UnitTestCase` class, but the guide says that is should work, so why isn't it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is that you're not including the phpunit.xml.dist file, which sits in the core folder.

Either run tests from there (./vendor/bin/phpunit ../modules/your_module) or specify that file with `-c`.

You can also provide your own phpunit.xml.dist file (see the Payment module as an example); then you can run PHPUnit from your module folder.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This fixed my issue. For those looking at this, I ran this command from CLI: vendor/bin/phpunit -c web/core/phpunit.xml.dist web/modules/custom

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today and noticed that I was using an older version of PHP Unit. After upgrading to the latest, the tests worked.